# Is it possible to set a default value for an argument in typescript when the type of the argument is a generic?

Tags: typescript, generics, casting

I am writing generic methods in order to use them in different frontend apps, and the idea is to be able to call the function `.postAsync<CustomModel>('www.mysite.com',..., CustomModel);`, and the intended response is a CustomModel object.

I would like to be able to set a default value for the second parameter, so that by default the value will be a different model and that can be overridden when needed.

How do I set the default value for an argument that is of type `Constructable<T>` where the interface Constructable means

```
interface Constructable<T> { new(params : any): T ;}
```

I have tried setting a default value of an interface which takes an argument and setting the argument to different types, but I always get the error `Type Constructable<CustomModel> is not assignable to type Constructable<T>`. I have also set the default type of T in the method generic to CustomModel and then tried this and get the same error.

```
interface Constructable<T> { new(params : any): T ;}


export default class WebapiBase {

    static async postAsync<T = CustomModel>(
        uri: string,
        body: object,
        headers: CustomHeaders = new CustomHeaders(),
        // This is the part giving errors
        model: Constructable<T> = <Constructable<CustomModel>>,): Promise<T> {
        return this.requestAsync<T>(model, HTTP_METHOD.POST, uri, headers, body);
    }

    private static async requestAsync<T>(
        model: Constructable<T>,
        method: HTTP_METHOD,
        uri: string,
        headers: CustomHeaders,
        body?: object): Promise<T> {
        const url = new URL(uri, window.location.origin);
        const request = this.buildRequest(url, method, headers, body);
        const bodyResponse = await fetch(request)
            .then(response => this.validate(response, request.headers))
            .then(validResponse => this.extractBody(validResponse))
            // Here is where the response body is being used to initialise one of the custom models that we are passing in. Code below
            .then(extractedBody => this.buildModel<T>(model, extractedBody))
            .catch((error) => { throw this.handleError(error); });
        return bodyResponse;
    }

    private static buildModel<T>(
        Model: Constructable<T>,
        params: ResponseBody,
    ): T {
        return new Model(params);
    }
}
```

I expected that I would not have to pass a model in to the method `postAsync()` and that it would always return a CustomModel object. But in actuality I get this error `Type Constructable<CustomModel> is not assignable to type Constructable<T>`

[Example in Playground, hover over Constructable in args to see error](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#src=interface%20Constructable%3CT%3E%20%7B%20new(params%20%3A%20any)%3A%20T%20%3B%7D%0D%0Aclass%20CustomModel%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20params%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(params%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.params%20%3D%20params%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20default%20class%20WebapiBase%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20async%20postAsync%3CT%20%3D%20CustomModel%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20uri%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20body%3A%20object%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20This%20is%20the%20part%20giving%20errors%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20model%3A%20Constructable%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%3CConstructable%3CCustomModel%3E%3E%2C)%3A%20Promise%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.requestAsync%3CT%3E(model%2C%20HTTP_METHOD.POST%2C%20uri%2C%20headers%2C%20body)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20static%20async%20requestAsync%3CT%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20model%3A%20Constructable%3CT%3E%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20method%3A%20HTTP_METHOD%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20uri%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20headers%3A%20CustomHeaders%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20body%3F%3A%20object)%3A%20Promise%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20url%20%3D%20new%20URL(uri%2C%20window.location.origin)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20request%20%3D%20this.buildRequest(url%2C%20method%2C%20headers%2C%20body)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20bodyResponse%20%3D%20await%20fetch(request)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.then(response%20%3D%3E%20this.validate(response%2C%20request.headers))%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.then(validResponse%20%3D%3E%20this.extractBody(validResponse))%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Here%20is%20where%20the%20response%20body%20is%20being%20used%20to%20initialise%20one%20of%20the%20custom%20models%20that%20we%20are%20passing%20in.%20Code%20below%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.then(extractedBody%20%3D%3E%20this.buildModel%3CT%3E(model%2C%20extractedBody))%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.catch((error)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20throw%20this.handleError(error)%3B%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20bodyResponse%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20static%20buildModel%3CT%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Model%3A%20Constructable%3CT%3E%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20params%3A%20ResponseBody%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Model(params)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: It's usually a good idea for code in questions to be a [mcve] that someone can just drop into an IDE and reproduce the issue without extraneous dependencies or errors... ideally there'd even be a link to a web IDE like [the Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//).  It's difficult to come up with concrete types that are known to be assignable to a generic type.  There's no guarantee that `CustomModel` will be assignable to `T` (a *default* is just a default, not a guarantee) so it's a type error to return a `CustomModel` when you need to return a `T`.

Comment: That's true, I'm really sorry. This is a pretty complicated example and tomorrow morning I will abstract out my issue to a minimal reproducible example. Thanks.

Comment: Added a link in the question to a playground example i just whipped up, it's not "Functioning" but it does get the same error or at least one of the errors I have got while fiddling with this issue. Will make it more concise soon. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, which was to return a default (in this case a generic object) in case a model was not passed.
Generally the fixes were:

- Change from having the model be typed as the `Constructable` interface but to use a union type of the `Constructable<T> | object`.
- Change the default where the model is being passed in to an Object.
- `buildModel()` function checks the type of the model and if it's an object, return the values passed in, if it's a constructable, then create an instance of it.

Check out how it's implemented in `postAsync` parameters, in the `ResponseModel` interface and in the `buildModel` method implemented in `requestAsync`:

```
interface Constructable<T> { new(params : any): T ;}
type ResponseModel<T> = Constructable<T> | Object;

export default class WebapiBase {
  static async postAsync<T = Object>(
      {
          uri = '',
          body = {},
          headers = new CustomHeaders(),
      }: PostRequestParams = {},
      // Here is where the defualt is implemented
      model: ResponseModel<T> = Object): Promise<T> {
      return this.requestAsync(model, HTTP_METHOD.POST, uri, headers, body);
  }
  private static async requestAsync<T = Object>(
      // This param accepts either a class or object
      model: ResponseModel<T>,
      method: HTTP_METHOD,
      uri: string,
      headers: CustomHeaders,
      body?: object): Promise<T> {
      const url = new URL(uri, window.location.origin);
      const request = this.buildRequest(url, method, headers, body);
      const bodyResponse = await fetch(request)
          .then(response => this.validate(response, request.headers))
          .then(validResponse => this.extractBody(validResponse))
          // Class instance or object returned here
          .then(extractedBody => this.buildModel(model, extractedBody))
          .catch((error) => { throw this.handleError(error); });
      return bodyResponse;
  }

  // Method that conditionally creates an instance of the passed in model
  // Or returns the object passed in if no model specified
  private static buildModel<T = Object>(
        Model: ResponseModel<T>,
        params: any,
    ): T {
        if (typeof Model === 'object') return params;
        return new Model(params);
  }
}
```